# IE8 Image won't scale

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer-8

Im trying to make a site compatible with IE8.  It all looks good save one image not scaling.  Any suggestions for a possible fix?  Heres the appropriate code.  The large picture is the one giving me issues

```
<div class = 'picture-container' id = 'pc1'>
    <div class = 'large-picture' id = 'lp1'>
        <figure style = 'float:left;max-width:45%;height:auto'>
            <img src = 'make-up_artist_dupontstudios.png' width = '100%' height = '100%' class = 'no-mobile'>
            <figcaption class = 'red-cap'>Our Set-Up</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <div class = 'picture-content'>
            <div class = 'picture-title'>BOUTIQUE PRODUCTION STUDIO</div>
            <div class = 'picture-text'>We built a boutique full service production studio that allows for
                one, two and three person ﬁlmed interviews and conversations.
                We have studio lights, a three camera set-up and remote
                monitoring. Additionally, our Inﬁnity Wall creates a clean and
                professional look that allows the ﬁlm to be about the message.</div>
            <div class = 'small-picture'>
                <img src = 'hair_and_makeup_dupontstudios.png' width = '175' height = '100'>
            </div>
            <div class = 'small-picture'>
                <img src = 'infinity_wall_dupontstudios.png' width = '175' height = '100'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which image? I see several.

Comment: Nevermind, didn't realize 'large' was the containing div class.

Comment: Need more information. How about a URL?